# Oracle SQL, varchar2, like with number

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

Given a table with the `NO_TELEPHONE` column of data type `VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)` which contain either 10- or 4-digit phone numbers. I have to ensure the last 4 digit of every number are unique (so `0000001111` and `1111` could not both exist).

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * from table where NO_TELEPHONE like '%1111';`
```

But it found 0 result, I really don't understand why.

After some tries, I got results with:

```
SELECT * from table where NO_TELEPHONE like '1111%';
SELECT * from table where NO_TELEPHONE like '______1111%';  (there is 6 '_' )
```

If I have `0000001111` in table and I want insert 0000, so program will do:

```
SELECT * from table where NO_TELEPHONE like '0000%';
```

and it will match with 0000001111, is not the behavior I wanted

Comment: There must be some (invisible?) character after the '1111' in those strings, hence the need for the '%' after the '1111' in the LIKE expressions.

Comment: If you [`dump()` the values](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions055.htm) found with those filters you can see exactly what they really contain.

Comment: @Zeldarck I have tidied the grammar in the post to, hopefully, make it clearer. Please review it and if it does not match with your requirements then you can click on the "edited X minutes ago" link and rollback the edit.

Comment: Sorry, I am French so english grammar it's not my force, thank for the edit.

@Tony Andrews@Alex Poole  Thank you, I didn't know the DUMP(), there is character '13' and '10' at the end of each my No_Telephone. I will review my java code for the insert :)

Comment: @Zeldarck - those are carriage return and new line (which I imagine you know) so yes you need to prevent those being included on insert - I guess you're loading data manually from a file?

Comment: @Alex Poole I am actually looking for that :)
I read it from a web app and convert long to string with String.format("%0" + format + "d%n", i); (format = 4 or 10 and i the phone number)  It's that function wich insert those. I will juste erase the two last char I think. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to select the data you can use:

```
SELECT RTRIM( no_telephone, CHR(13)||CHR(10) ) AS no_telephone
FROM   table_name
WHERE  RTRIM( no_telephone, CHR(13)||CHR(10) ) LIKE '%1111';
```

However, if you want to correct the data::

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    no_telephone = RTRIM( no_telephone, CHR(13)||CHR(10) )
WHERE  SUBSTR( no_telephone, -2 ) = CHR(13)||CHR(10);
```

Or, if there are more issues and you want to replace all non-digits then:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET  no_telephone = REGEXP_REPLACE( no_telephone, '\D+' );
```

Then you can enforce the uniqueness of the last 4 characters:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_name__no_telephone__u
  ON table_name ( SUBSTR( no_telephone, -4 ) );
```

and you can enforce the format of the column using:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT table_name__no_telephone__chk
  CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE(no_telephone, '^\d{4}\d{6}?$' ) );
```

Comment: Very strange, it didn't work with your regex but work with this one: `^(\d{10}|\d{4})$`
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try using RTRIM

```
 SELECT * from table where RTRIM(NO_TELEPHONE, ' ' , chr(13), chr(10)) like '%1111';
```

Comment: Hum, it's sound good, but that throw an error for the char(10) and char(13), say "00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"". It's an Oracle database

Comment: Yes there was a mistake  .. CHR instead of char